# How to show a Keynote presentation on other platforms?

Tags: macbook-pro, keynote

I will make a presentation about my project in my college, and I will use Keynote to make the presentation file because I found it better than Powerpoint.

I have a Macbook Pro and I can't connect it to the projector directly.

Is there any way to use the Keynote file on Windows with all the features?

Comment: What connector has your projector?

Comment: I don't know, but it is the common one.

Comment: If it is an old one with 3 rows of 5 pins looking like: https://www.google.fr/search?q=vga&source=lnms&tbm=isch, then it is a VGA connector dating 1987.

Answer (score 5):

From your `Keynote` document select:

```
File > Export > PPT...
```

or better (to avoid most problems with PowerPoint format):

```
File > Export > PDF...
```

This last format will work perfectly on any Unix and any Windows.

---

Warning: test these formats on the target system before a serious presentation.

With both formats, video, animation, transitions and presenter notes will be lost.

If your projector is of the VGA era (see https://www.google.fr/search?q=vga&source=lnms&tbm=isch) then I would advise you to:

1. Stay with Keynote (this software is still many years ahead of many others and mostly of PowerPoint).
2. Buy a Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter.

Comment: But I want to show the presentation in full-screen mode. So how can I do that with a PDF file.

Comment: A PDF can be used in full screen mode on Windows. Just ask the Windows genius which key combination to use to to switch to the next or the previous page.

Comment: The key combination may be different depending on the PDF viewing application.

Answer (score 1):

No - all the features require a Mac. You can get a large subset of most features if you transfer a Mac keynote to iOS and use it for presenting, but you'll have to dumb down your presentation substantially or render it as a movie to have it play on Windows.

Your best bet is getting the connector you need to have the Mac connect to the projector. Other than someone preventing me from physically accessing the projector cables, I've not seen a projector where a Mac couldn't be connected and a PC could be connected. Perhaps you have some strange situation, but most likely you can get connected with an inexpensive adapter.